# Как убрать ошибку "parameter flags unfilled" в super().__init__() на Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Есть 2 класса, у каждого при инициализации происходит вызов `super().__init__()`.

Скажите пожалуйста, как убрать ошибку:

> "parameter flags unfilled" в super().**init**?

```
class SkeletonOfWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        object_of_buttons = SetOfButtons(self)

        self.build_skeleton_of_window_with_constants()
        self.build_background_image_of_skeleton()
        object_of_buttons.__init__(self)
    ...


class SetOfButtons(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, application):
        super().__init__()
        self.build_file_button(application)
        self.build_paint_button(application)
    ...
```

Comment: Приведите [mre] ошибки

Comment: @dIm0n, программа работает, но PyCharm подсвечивает желтым строку с super().__init__() и говорит "parameter flags unfilled"

Comment: @GunTHE, попробуйте установить пакет [`PyQt5-stubs`](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5-stubs/). он помогает редакторам разбирать код с `PyQt5`

Comment: Спасибо, попробовал, но не работает

Comment: Не воспроизводится: `PyCharm 2020.2.2 (Community Edition)` OS: Debian testing, `sudo apt install python3-pyqt5`, `python 3.8.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По предоставленному отрывку, не понятно, что у вас происходит.
Интуитивно, я бы предложил попробовать так:

```
class SetOfButtons(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SetOfButtons, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        
#                                vvvvvvvvvv <-- ???        
#        self.build_file_button(application)
#        self.build_paint_button(application)
        

class SkeletonOfWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.object_of_buttons = SetOfButtons(self)

        self.build_skeleton_of_window_with_constants()
        self.build_background_image_of_skeleton()
        
# ???        object_of_buttons.__init__(self)
    ...
```

Comment: Всё равно, PyCharm продолжает подсвечивать это :(. Но спасибо большое за помощь

Comment: @GunTHE у меня нет  PyCharm. Скажите пожалуйста, какую из предложенных мною строк вам подсвечивает и с каким сообщением.

Comment: "super(SetOfButtons, self).__init__(parent)" продолжается подсвечиваться с той же ошибкой. Вообще, на приложении это не сказывается, но PyCharm почему-то подсвечивает это.

Comment: @GunTHE, то, что PyCharm **подсвечивает** не является ошибкой. У виджетов в конструкторе можно передавать флаги окна, но это опционально, но PyCharm по какой-то причине этого не понял, поэтому подсветил. Для ознакомления: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#QWidget